# Android Special Character: &quot;

Tags: android, json, string

I'm parsing JSON from an API but in the strings I get back, I get "&qout;" For example, I have a string that is returned that says "The movie &qout;Her&qout; is a spectacular movie."

I want it to say "The movie 'Her' is a spectacular movie" but I have no idea how to update the string that is being returned from the API before I display it to the user in a TextView. The actual string in the JSON return includes &quot. I get the string through JSON parsing and I don't know if that makes things more difficult.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: can u post ur service code?

Comment: @DIVA are you asking if my string is "utf-8" or "ISO-8859-1"? I've tried both. Currently using "ISO-8859-1".

Comment: you can use Html.fromHtml http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/Html.html#fromHtml(java.lang.String)

Comment: @SirwanAfifi tried that. it doesn't work.

Comment: @fadelakin m saying script from where u r getting response

Comment: @DIVA I'm sorry I don't understand. I'm getting the response from here http://api.icndb.com/jokes/random Not sure if it's what you want though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could always parse your string and replace the `&quot;` with `'`

```
string.replace("&quot;", "'");
```

I know it's not very elegant, but it gets the job done. But, along with what DIVA is asking, a valid question might be: why are you getting &quot in your JSON response from the API?

Also, you didn't mention if you were using a 3rd party JSON parser or the built in JsonReader?

Comment: Your method work. No idea why the API would return &quot; Sorry but I was using a 3rd party JSON parser. Don't really know why. I'm just starting out with Android. Thanks for the help.

I did `string.replace("&quot;", "\"");`

Answer (score 2):

You can also use

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
    Html.fromHtml("`The movie &quot;Her&quot; is a spectacular movie.`", HtmlCompat.FROM_HTML_MODE_LEGACY)
} else {
    Html.fromHtml("`The movie &quot;Her&quot; is a spectacular movie.`")
}
```